# How to unit test when a function calls another function returning a boolean?

Tags: java, unit-testing

Below is an code which I need to unit test. I would write 2 unit test cases for `getFoo`, one for `true(x==5)` and other for `false(x==10)`. 
My question is do I need to write two unit test functions even for `convertWrapper` for true and false case ? In my opinion I should, to ensure that in future someone does not cause a change in convertWrapper, resulting in regression. But just wondering whats considered a widely adopted practice in such cases.

```
public boolean getFoo(int x) {
    return x == 5;
}

public boolean convertWrapper(char ch) {
    int x = (int)ch;
    return getFoo(x);
}
```

Comment: I would say writing unit testing for all the public methods is a good practice

Comment: I think your opinion is generally correct.  Even though the name `convertWrapper` makes it seem like the **definition** of the function is that it simply calls `getFoo`, that wouldn't prevent some bonehead from screwing it up in the future.

Answer (score 2):

One option: ensure convertWrapper calls and returns the result of getFoo, and unit test getFoo.

Mocks help do integration tests like that.

Comment: This is a good option *if* the high level contract of `convertWrapper` specifies that it always returns the same result as `getFoo`. So whether or not this is an appropriate option depends on requirement details that the OP left out. This isn't a criticism, just wanted to point that out to the OP.

Comment: @JasonC Correct. Attempting to ensure nobody changed convertWrapper is why I suggested it at all, but more details might be necessary. I don't know if this is the actual example or not-at some point unit tests become wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to write unit tests in general.  They should be simple and easy to maintain.  If using multiple tests methods is the simplest and easiest to maintain do that.  In general, I try not to write too much boiler plate code in unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself - what is the general contract of `convertWrapper`.  If it's to return true for a particular input, and return false for any other input, then test that it does that.  The fact that it is implemented via `getFoo` is irrelevant to how you'll unit test it.

If somebody in the future changes the implementation so that it still returns true or false for the same inputs as before, but doesn't use `getFoo` then that should NOT break the test.

Since `getFoo` is public, it should have its own tests.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you probably do want to write separate cases, because your opinion is generally correct and is precisely the type of situation proper testing is meant to avoid:

> In my opinion I should, to ensure that in future someone does not
>   cause a change in convertWrapper, resulting in regression.

Your unit tests should test the high-level functionality of your code. Your unit tests are unaware of implementation details, they only test that the terms of the "contract" are met. Since you have two public methods that, on a high level, do two separate things (we presume - your requirements weren't stated or documented), then you have two separate tests.

Eliminating one of the tests because you, as the developer, implicitly know that the implementations are the same suddenly brings information about implementation details into the testing realm, which is asking for problems and regressions in the future.

One option that Dave Newton pointed out in his answer is to write a unit test that essentially ensures that `convertWrapper(ch) == getFoo((int)ch)` for all relevant `ch`. That is a fine suggestion and may very well be appropriate, but only if the high level requirement of `convertWrapper` is that it "returns the same value as `getFoo`". Again, your tests should reflect your requirements.

Of course, that doesn't mean it's somehow against the law to eliminate the test. The devil won't necessarily lay claim to your soul if you do it (although sometimes I wish that was the usual consequence). If your application is rather simple, or if you are willing to accept the associated risks, then even a simple "@todo Test me" documentation marker may be enough to get by. It is sometimes OK to take shortcuts now and then *but only if you truly understand and accept the implications* -- only you can save you from yourself. :)

But, in the general case, yes, two tests. Then you can "fire-and-forget" your tests, and never have to remember that special exception to the rules you made in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you need to write only two unit tests for `getFoo`?

Of course, you know that the method really can only go one of two ways, but the caller doesn't. It might seem ridiculous with a method this trivial, but you need to think in terms of the contract for the method. Maybe you need to test with 5, then 0, then a negative number, then a really high positive number, or whatever other weird case a caller expects you to be able to handle.

Similar with `convertWrapper`. You know it calls `getFoo` and `getFoo` has really only two paths, but you can't let yourself think that way.

The bottom line is you need to define the contract for your methods and run enough tests where you feel confident that your public methods satisfy that contract.